# I'm getting different public key hashes when creating new wallet with Taquito InMemorySigner x when creating with Kukai wallet. Why?

Tags: taquito, wallets, temple

I'm writing a dApp where I need to create a "native" (not beacon) wallet so it can perform some automatic operations.

Occurs that, with the same mnemonic words used to create a wallet in Kukai, I'm getting different public key hashes when creating wallets with Taquito "InMemorySigner".

I am using defaults from Taquito "InMemorySigner", i.e., curve = 'ed25519' and derivationPath "44'/1729'/0'/0'". I imagine Kukai must be using something different.

But Temple wallet mnemonics work on Taquito "InMemorySigner" (giving same public hashes).

What are the best practices here? I want the user to import a wallet, regardless where it came from.

Answer (score 1):

Could you help confirm if `Temple wallet` returns the same `pkh` as Kukai?

In advanced options in `Kukai`, there is the ability to select `HD wallet` or `legacy wallet`.

Could you confirm that the key you are looking for is a `tz1...`?

I have just checked a test mnemonic that I have on all 3 Kukai, Temple, InMemorySigner.fromMnemonic and was able to recreate the `pkh` in all 3

If you are trying to get the same `curve` and `derivation path` account, then there should be no problem with the `InMemorySigner.fromMnemonic` to recreate it.

I found that some mnemonics are not encodable for one (possibly more, but I have yet to see any) of the curve derivation requirements.

Could you share some code of where the result is going wrong to understand better what may be happening?

Post-added code, for illustrative purposes:

```
                const params =
                {
                    mnemonic: "[my 24 word mnemonic]",
                    password: "[myPassphrase]"
                }            

                const TezosNative = new TezosToolkit(this.configuredRpcProvider);
                const signer = InMemorySigner.fromMnemonic(params);
                TezosNative.setSignerProvider(signer);
                await TezosNative.signer.publicKeyHash()
                .then((publicKeyHash) => {
                    console.log(publicKeyHash);
                });
```

This returns me             :  **tz1UYo2sTAE5pEs6SeCT9wg3FrxcxDcoHc1k**
Kukai and Temple returns me :  **tz1W4Vs3VEw87yVMHY9QTH738NDWYNTqmwGR**

With same 24 mnemonic words and passphrase.

Comment: Dear Zainen, thanks for your quick reply. I will check everything you mentioned. But probably the issue is regarding HD wallet in Kukai and legacy on InMemorySigner. I will check it and come back here later.

Comment: Now I have imported successfully the wallet in Kukai, with the public key hash given by the InMemorySigner. Although when the wallet was original created on Kukai, the public key hash was different...  And with this latter mentioned public key hash, Kukai doesn't accept it. Strange...

Comment: If I import the *.tez file that I've downloaded initially from Kukai (upon wallet creation), it works. I open the wallet that has a different public key hash. If I reveal the mnemonics of this on Kukai, they are the same of the InMemorySinger's. And the passphrase of both are the same... I am beginning to think that the password that Kukai asks to protect the wallet (besides the passphrase) might be part of what they use to encript everything... Thus the difference.

Comment: There is a chance that the part of code Kukai uses for interpreting mnemonics are parsing it differently to what we use in Taquito.

I am not entirely sure what library Kukai uses to do so, or if they have any in-house solutions for that. But in Taquito, we rely on some 3rd party packages that we've tested against the octez-client.

Comment: Looking at Kukais code there is a difference of how the seed is generated by using @tezos-crypto-tools/crypto-utils and ours using bip39

this is possibly amendable for consistency however it would take more digging to understand the differences between the two packages and what tezos would like to have as a consistent rule of mnemonic to seed

Comment: @LuizMilfont could you confirm if your encrypted pkh is the same for Kukai and temple?

Comment: Zainen, I've just imported the wallet on Temple, with the same 24 mnemonic words generated by Kukai, plus same passphrase. Temple has given me the same public key hash that Kukai did. They both differ from what Taquito InMemorySigner produced as pkh.

Comment: Could you for a sanity check test the InMemorySigner.fromMnemonic the password = '' ?

Comment: I found out that, if I pass an empty string in the "password" field, it works, giving me the same pkh as Kukai and Temple: tz1W4Vs3VEw87yVMHY9QTH738NDWYNTqmwGR. Could Taquito InMemorySigner be ignoring passphrase?

Comment: its the other way around I believe. the password is not used since its impossible to recover your account or help to recover it by the wallet provider

Comment: there is no recovery possible if you lose your password for the encrypted mnemonic

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145355/discussion-between-zainen-and-luiz-milfont).

Answer (score 0):

I'm starting to believe that there were some kind of error in the moment that Kukai generated the wallet and it went without the passphrase. I will create other sets of mnemonic words + passphrases to check it out.